# How do I set persistence using firebase and typscript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set the persistence to 'Session' using typescript/react, but getting type errors.

Here is some of code:

```
import { auth } from "../auth/firebase";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  setPersistence,
  signInWithCustomToken,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
} from "firebase/auth";
```

This is my useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("here useEffect");
  
    auth.setPersistence(auth.Auth.SESSION.NONE); //Property 'Auth' does not exist on type 'Auth'.

    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => //this works fine
```

I tried a different solution I found here, that looked like this:

```
setPersistence(auth, {type: 'LOCAL'});
```

This didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#modifying_the_auth_state_persistence) for an example.

```
import { getAuth, setPersistence, browserSessionPersistence } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence);
// it returns a promise...
```

Also see the [API documentation for setPersistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#setpersistence).

Answer (score 1):

This table expands on the documentation [Supported types of Auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence). The TypeScript constants (TS const) are new values used with the modular API (in lieu of the old enum values used in the namespaced API).

| Enum | Persistence (TS const) | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` | `browserLocalPersistence` | State will be persisted even when the browser window is closed. An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state. |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION` | `browserSessionPersistence` | State will only persist in the current session or tab, and will be cleared when the tab or window in which the user authenticated is closed. Applies only to web apps. |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE` | `inMemoryPersistence` | State will be stored in memory and will be cleared when the window or activity is refreshed. |

### Example using Web modular API

```js
import { getAuth, setPersistence, inMemoryPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
  });
```

### Same example using Web namespaced API

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = firebase.auth()

auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)
```